# Changing Cursor Dynamically according to the control

Tags: c#, .net, user-controls

I am creating a custom control. On that control I have around 20 sub controls. When i move the cursor on my User Control, i want the cursor to be changed according to sub control it is moving on.

**Eg:**

```
User Control
--Control 1 : if(Condition 1) { Mouse - Wait } else { Mouse - Default }
--Control 2 : if(Condition 1) { Mouse - Hand } else { Mouse - Default }
--Control 3 : Mouse - Default
```

......so on.

Is there any way to determine on MouseMove Event of User Control that i am moving on which sub control so that i can change my cursor in a single event.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to rely on events, can use the `Cursor Property` of the given control. For example, if you have three TextBoxes, you can change this property in the "properties box" on the "Design View" or just write:

```
textBox1.Cursor = Cursors.WaitCursor;
textBox2.Cursor = Cursors.Hand;
textBox3.Cursor = Cursors.Default;
```

The cursor would show the given shape when "entering" in each Textbox.

Comment: Damn, never did this and even never knew this property existed.
THX, too.

Comment: @icbytes LOL. No problem. But this is not a competition: it is nice to get some ranking points but you shouldn't feel bad (not even half-bad) if a better solution appears: the OP gets the help he/she is looking for and your knowledge also improves.

Comment: @varocarbas : I have updated the question after your reply. Because there may be chances that i have to change the cursor on some condition dynamically. Sorry, forget to mention earlier.

Comment: @Lokesh There is no problem at all with what I am proposing: you can change the .Cursor property as much as you wish from anywhere in the code. Whenever the new condition pops up just change the Cursor property of the given control and you will be sure that every time the mouse "enters" in this control it would show the image you want. You don't need to track if the mouse is inside the control via events, this property does it for you.

Comment: No, did not see it as competition, I was wondering about my "missing knowledge" and how easy it can be, if one inspect the properties properly :-)

Comment: @icbytes OK there is no "missing knowledge". Just realising that you don't know something (and I am sure that you don't know lots of things, exactly than myself or any other person), learn it and start applying it. If you recognise that my answer is better, you should start using this approach instead yours (and, ideally, recognise it via upvote for future readers :))

Comment: @icbytes see our different behaviours: I would automatically +1 your answer in case of thinking that it is better than mine (even if it has something worthy or you shown an attitude worthy to be appraised/seen by others). If your answer proves mine to be wrong (or impractical) and thus useless for the OP or future readers, I would delete it immediately. I don't get too many upvotes (most of my reputation comes from accepted answers) but all the ones I got were because my answers were recognised as worthy by others; don't you think that this is how things should be? Same thing for -1s?

Comment: @varocarbas : I tried your solution, but that cursor is not changing when i am simply moving on that control but it changes when i clicks on that control and after releasing the click the cursor again becomes default. Please check at your end or let me know if i am missing something.

Comment: @Lokesh Write my code on the Form Load event and see that you will not get this behaviour anymore. The reason why it behaves as you say is, most likely, because you wrote this code in the click event of the given control.

Comment: @icbytes PS: I am telling you all that because yesterday (and some days before too), I have observed a pretty curious behaviour (at least to me): people coming to the only question I have written (which was just to see how was it... I got a quick answer with votes and thus wasn't able to delete it) an -1ing just for revenge (not sure of what as far as I rarely -1 anyone). I think that this people have forgotten about what all this is about: creating a worthy site based on correctness, fairness and honestly. If you want to learn and become better would get a reward. But this is just my opinion

Comment: @varocarbas : I have written this code in the form load event only. I understand what are you trying to say. But that does not seems to work. :(

Comment: @Lokesh this code works. What you might be doing is over-writing the behaviour (by using the code above too, for example). Open a new project, put 3 textboxes on it, write this code in the form load event and it will work for sure. Once you confirm that it works, you can write here you code to get some further help if you don't understand what is going wrong with your original code.

Comment: @varocarbas : OK, It worked for other controls but not for picture box  when i am redrawing the picture dynamically. Setting the pictureBox.Cursor property is not working but this.Cursor property is working perfectly. But for that i need to know which Control is being hovered by the mouse pointer. We are again at the first page now.

Comment: @Lokesh this is starting to become a bit confusing (and I am starting to not like it too much): you have asked how to change the cursor on account of conditions. I have explained how to do it. Your problem is solved. If you didn't explained your problem properly, please, feel free to edit your question and I MIGHT answer it further (remember: just one question per post). Write down the code you have written what it does and what you want it to do.

Comment: +1 It is a good approach. But your solution is not working in all the conditions for me.

Comment: @Lokesh thanks. But I am afraid that it is a perfectly-valid approach which works in any case. What you are most likely doing is overwriting the same behaviour and thus getting a wrong output, please paste the code associated to the given control where you are getting problems, such that I (or any other person) can help you.

Comment: @varocarbas : Finally got what was the problem. You were right, i was again setting the cursor to default somewhere in the middle of the code. Thanks for pointing in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

You can assign to EACH usercontrol's mouse-over or You can assign to ONE event handler, which is the same for all Your controls. Depending on which technique You choose, You then can set the cursor, the second technique requires to a ) a hardcoded if / else or switch case  or b ) reflection casting sender to right type and then setting the mouse-cursor.
Did this help ?

Comment: Both the solutions are realistic but i am trying to implement a global approach. In future, if I want to add some new controls than i have to handle their mouse events again. I am looking for a solution by which only one event can be changed to do the needful on the basis of control ID or so.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this way. Suppose you have three buttons having name as button1, button2 & button3.

1. Write this on form load

> this.button1.MouseHover += new System.EventHandler(this.MouseHover);
>   this.button2.MouseHover += new System.EventHandler(this.MouseHover);
>   this.button3.MouseHover += new System.EventHandler(this.MouseHover);

1. Now write this as new event :

   private void MouseHover(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
       Button oButton = (Button)sender;
       if (oButton.Name == "button1")
       {
           oButton.Cursor = Cursors.WaitCursor;
       }
       else if (oButton.Name == "button2")
       {
           oButton.Cursor = Cursors.Hand;
       }
       else if (oButton.Name == "button3")
       {
           oButton.Cursor = Cursors.Default;
       }
   }

It will work as you need.

Thanks

Comment: Cant the event be of User control and i can check which sub control is hovered? Otherwise I have to create events for each control on my user control, although the method name will be same(your approach).

Comment: If you use the Cursor property, why you need to rely on events? Don't you know that the Cursor property is precisely applied just to the given control, that is, to when the mouse enters on it? You are basically rechecking the same thing twice.

Comment: @Lokesh as said in my comment above, the Cursors property checks everything for you (exactly the same than an event), what this code does is repeating things.

Comment: It seems as if You should create an eventhandler for usercontrol.controladded. Inside this handler You should programatically add a handler to addedControl.MouseOver.
The usercontrol itself should be extended with a new event like "MouseOverElementChanged" and be fired, when Control.MouseOver for each subelement comes. Then You would have a) the automatic registration, if You plan to extend the usercontrol in the future.
b) the event itself comes from usercontrol
c) it is all inside usercontrol encapsulated.
What about this approach ?
Should even work in design time .

Comment: @icbytes I am afraid that you haven't got the point still: the events in this code make sure that the mouse is on the given control, this is a redundand analysis as far as it is implicit in the Cursor property. You are doing the same than textBox1.Font = newFont being called from the textChange event: the Font will be applied to any new character entered (you don't need to check that the character is effectively being inputed).

Comment: All our approaches seem not to fit for op.
So while following his last argument "cant the event be of usercontrol" I thought to hear something like : he is probably working on a framework or at least a part of it.

Comment: @icbytes the point I am intending to make is that the property this answer is using (and the one, most likely, you would be relying on too) accounts implicitely for the fact that the mouse is inside the control. Every time you do control.Cursor = typeOfCursor, .NET understands that the cursor will only be changed when it is inside the bounds of the given control. If you want to use Events and make them truly relevant, you shouldn't rely on control.Cursor, but on the general Cursor (independently upon any control in the form). I hope I made my point clear.

Comment: ....upon any control in the form .... that means for sure, to work with "usercontrol.cursor" and not "subcontrol_in_usercontrol.cursor".
If that was Your intention, then Your point now is clear to me.

Comment: @icbytes I will put you a different example which might help to transmit ideas properly: if you want to track when the letter "e" is pressed anywhere (in any control of your form or when using a different program), you would have to rely on a global hook. The keyEnter event of each control only tracks the key being pressed (int this case "e") when the given control is selected. curcontrol.cursor works more or less the same, that is, it changes the cursor when you enter in the given control (ANY control) and that's why checking via events whether the cursor is inside this control is redundant.

Comment: @icbytes thus I didn't make any difference between controls (now the OP is complaining about this approach not working with certain type of controls, what is not true; he is doing something else wrong). If you want to use curcontrol.Controls (where curcontrol can be any control), you don't need to bring the events into account at all (not to determine if the cursor is inside the given control or not). If you want to rely on events anyway and want to make them useful (not just write code with no real utility), you might want to affect the cursor globally, instead via curControl.Cursor.